# does ssis data flow commit when stopping mid process

Tags: ssis, dataflow

I know I can test this out pretty easily but dont have access to SSIS right now does any one know if a ssis data flow commits the inserted records if it is stopped mid process.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

That would be dependent on the setting for TransactionOption.  This can be set on the package, container or task level.   It defaults to not supported, which would commit the records.

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms137690(v=sql.105).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms137690%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)